# Changing domain of solution in Integer Programming

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, integer-programming

I'm given an inequality $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 \geq c_1$ where $a, c, x_1, x_2$ are integers and $x_1, x_2 \text{ are either } 1 \text{ or }  0$.

I'd like to construct another inequality $b_1y_1 + b_2y_2 \geq c_2$ where $b, c, y_1, y_2$ are integers  in range $[-k, k]$ in a way s.t. first inequality is satisfiable iff second inequality is satisfiable.

I've tried to map $x_1, x_2$ to $y_1, y_2$ via affine transformation but it doesn't seem like the right approach.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: I take it $k$ is fixed? Do you know anything about the signs of the symbols in the first constraint?

Comment: @prubin yes k is fixed. No assumption about the signs of coefficients.

Comment: Also just to be clear, the domain requirement $\{-k,\dots,k\}$ applies not just to the $y$ variables but also to the coefficients $b$ and $c_2$?

Comment: @prubin This is correct. In second inequality, range condition applies both to coefficients and variables.